# Google play(market) notifications of new ratings comments

Tags: android, app-store, google-play

Quick question, because I can't seem to find anything. Is there any way to enable some kind of notification when your app gets a new comment/rating? I've missed a couple and its annoying checking almost every day just to be sure!

Thanks!

Comment: When i answer a similar question, my question will more downvoted and will be a closed =(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with [Andlytics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.betaapps.andlytics&hl=en), but the free version doesn't allow notifications (need to pay $2.99 for that). Though the free one does have a one-touch way to view your stats and ratings without invoking a web browser/logging in which I find pretty useful.

Answer (score 3):

No the only way is to keep checking the android play market.  Just bookmark it on your phone or something.  That is what I do with [my application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ewe.radixcalculator) which is a free calculator for developers.

You can access your applications page in the market on anything with an web browser by using the following url:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=[put_your_root_package_name_here]

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: You know this gave me an idea.  I could create an Android application that would periodically check your applications site for new reviews, ratings, and +1s, would you be interested in it?

Comment: Well I will have to download that application and give it a try. Thanks @Tim.